# how to set background image using setElementStyle in angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set background image using setElementStyle as below but not working.

```
this.renderer.setElementStyle(document.body, 'backgroundImage', this.backgroundImageUrl);
```

I also tried,

```
this.renderer.setElementStyle(document.body, 'background-image', this.backgroundImageUrl);
```

Please let me know if it's possible to set background image using setElementStyle?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`setElementStyle` is from Renderer. And it is depreciated. Renderer2 uses `setStyle`:

```
setStyle(el: any, style: string, value: any, flags?: RendererStyleFlags2): void
```

And import it:

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `this.backgroundImageUrl` inside url() then above code will work fine.

```
this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'backgroundImage', 'url('+this.backgroundImageUrl+')');
```